# Cordova plugin to generate pdf in the client-side (cesarvr)

Tags: cordova, pdf, cordova-plugins, phonegap

in phone gap apache build in iOS.. how to change view from portrait to landscape..?

```
makePDFAndShare: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    progressShow();
    /* generate pdf using url. */
    pdf.htmlToPDF({
        url: this.$urlShare.val(),
        landscape : "portrait",
        type: "share"
    }, this.success, this.failure);


},
```

[THIS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0TDe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using landscape instead of portrait?

```
makePDFAndShare: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    progressShow();
    /* generate pdf using url. */
    pdf.htmlToPDF({
        url: this.$urlShare.val(),
        landscape : "landscape",
        type: "share"
    }, this.success, this.failure);
}
```